# Max Planck and energy quantization idea

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, physicists, energy, planck

Did Planck have an intuition behind the idea of energy quantization of atomic oscillators and radiation, or was it just a mathematical trick to derive his distribution law?

Comment: I think this question belongs more on the history of science and mathematics stack exchange: [hsm.se]

Comment: That's the definition of physics at a fundamental level: tricky ways to translate the world & experimental results into maths. So he was physicizing (not sure about the word). How did newton realize $F=m\,a$? That'd be complicated I think...Oh, actually is exists [on this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/how-did-newton-discover-his-second-law)

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~krasny/math156_article_planck.pdf

Comment: I'll migrate this question to [hsm.se], because it seems to be less about the physical basis of energy quantization than about the thought process Planck used to get there.

Comment: He may well have gone down other paths to solve the Ultraviolet Catastrophe problem, but once it's shown to meet experimental data, it becomes a useful tool.  Since it's really just a "standing wave" theory, I am not sure it is directly related to quantization of electron levels.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft hmm I don't think so, as it is non dependent on the structure, just on T...it doesn't even depends on non uniformities as far as I understand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did Planck derive the black body radiation formula without using the Bose statistics?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3404/how-did-planck-derive-the-black-body-radiation-formula-without-using-the-bose-st)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Planck's quantization idea](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7847/plancks-quantization-idea)