# How did they explain the radiation from hot objects at different wavelengths before the concept of atom was widely accepted?

Tags: physics, chemistry, atomic-theory, radiation

I was reading about blackbody radiation and came across the following quote.

> Planck did not believe in atoms, nor did he think the second law of
> thermodynamics should be statistical because probability does not
> provide an absolute answer, and Boltzmann’s entropy law rested on the
> hypothesis of atoms and was statistical. But Planck was unable to find
> a way to reconcile his Blackbody equation with continuous laws such as
> Maxwell’s wave equations. So in what Planck called “an act of
> desperation,” he turned to Boltzmann’s atomic law of entropy as it was
> the only one that made his equation work. Therefore, he used
> Boltzmann’s constant k and his new constant h to explain the Blackbody
> radiation law which became widely known through his published paper.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#History

> In atomic physics, the Bohr model or Rutherford–Bohr model, presented
> by Niels Bohr and Ernest Rutherford in 1913, is a system consisting of
> a small, dense nucleus surrounded by orbiting electrons—similar to the
> structure of the Solar System, but with attraction provided by
> electrostatic forces in place of gravity. It came after the solar
> system Joseph Larmor model (1897), the cubical model (1902), the
> Hantaro Nagaoka Saturnian model (1904), the plum pudding model (1904),
> the quantum Arthur Haas model (1910), the Rutherford model (1911), and
> the nuclear quantum John William Nicholson model (1912). The
> improvement over the 1911 Rutherford model mainly concerned the new
> quantum physical interpretation introduced by Haas and Nicholson, but
> forsaking any attempt to align with classical physics radiation.
>
> The model's key success lay in explaining the Rydberg formula for the
> spectral emission lines of atomic hydrogen. While the Rydberg formula
> had been known experimentally, it did not gain a theoretical
> underpinning until the Bohr model was introduced. Not only did the
> Bohr model explain the reasons for the structure of the Rydberg
> formula, it also provided a justification for the fundamental physical
> constants that make up the formula's empirical results.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model

**Question**

It seems like most scientists of 19th century did not believe in atoms and possibly the belief in atoms started gaining traction around 1900.

How did they explain the radiation resulting from the materials during that era when the belief in atoms was not widespread? For example, when an object is heated why it starts emitting radiation at different wavelengths.

I'm asking this question because I think this 'misunderstanding' of pre-atomic era was at the core of ultraviolet catastrophe. The electrons emitting quanta of radiation when jumping from one orbital to another was an outcome of 1913 Bohr model atomic model.

Comment: ‘Atoms’ were well known from chemistry. Their nuclear structure was not known until Rutherford, Geiger, and Marsden in 1911. Lack of belief in atoms was not an issue.

Comment: Thank you. The first quote mentions that Planck did not believe in atoms. I've read in the past that there were many 19th century scientists who did not believe in atoms but I only included the mention of Planck to make the point.

Comment: Larmor formula was known from before Planck. Electromagnetic theory predicts that any changing electrical current produces an electromagnetic wave and it was well known that all matter was composed of positively and negatively charged fluids that could produce the currents. I would look at Boltzmann's papers for a clue, he derived Stefan-Boltzmann law using classical arguments (although he probably believed in atoms).

Comment: Thank you! But Larmor formula only came out around 1897 which showed that an accelerating charge radiated energy. But the scientists were doing work on blackbody related problems long before 1897 therefore they must have had some other explanation to explain for the radiation.

Comment: Many scientists, including most chemists, did believe in atoms since the early 19th century, but there was also strong resistance among physicists (Mach et al.). The favored approach was to use general thermodynamic considerations, later also statistical mechanics, without specific material hypotheses you have in mind as explanations. That is what researchers of radiation did, from Kirchhoff to Planck and Jeans. The "ultraviolet catastrophe" is a historical fiction invented later, see [How did Planck derive the black body radiation formula?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/3408/55).

Comment: @Conifold Thank you! So, is it fair to say that they didn't care about underlying mechanism responsible for radiation? They just thought as an object is heated, it radiates different types of radiation?

Comment: @PG1995 Boltzmann seems to consider atoms as the source, however his derivation of Stefa-Boltzmann law does no depend on any microscopic theory, just in the fact that the surface is emitting radiation.

Comment: It is not that they did not care. They considered composition of matter hypotheses to be highly speculative and controversial, and preferred derivations that relied on their specifics as little as possible. For example, Planck's "underlying mechanism" featured some generic "ideal oscillators", and it mattered very little to their statistics what they actually might be. Kirchhoff and  Stefan-Boltzmann did not even use statistics, only thermodynamics.

Comment: Thank you, both of you. I get it now.